# Multiple sprintf calls to format a string piece by piece

Tags: c, printf

I have a problem wherein I want to call sprintf(or similar function) multiple times for it to replace the format specifier with the data values one at a time,

For E.g.: `char *str = "Temperature is %f, Humidity is %d, wait for %d secs";`
Now I receive the argument data in multiple variables and I want to be able to call

```
float temp = 23.45;
char humidity = 87;
int time = 3;
sprintf(buf, str, temp);
sprintf(buf, str, humidity);
sprintf(buf, str, time);`
```

However we see the first call to sprintf itself will replace first `%f` with `23.45` and other format specifiers with garbage or 0. What I expect in `str` after first sprintf call is
`"Temperature is 23.45, Humidity is %d, wait for %d secs"`

So I know I cannot use sprintf or snprintf for this, is there another string library call which does what I a expecting?

I tried this in online gdb and sprintf is not the function I am looking for.

Comment: Why is `sprintf(buf, "Temperature is %.2f, Humidity is %d, wait for %d secs", temp,  humidity, time);` unacceptable?

Answer (score 3):

You CAN use `sprintf()`.

Try something like this:

```
float temp = 23.45;
char humidity = 87;
int time = 3;

char *at = buf;
at += sprintf( at, "Temp: %.1f ", temp );
at += sprintf( at, "Humidity: %d ", (int)humidity );
at += sprintf( at, "Time: %d", time );
puts( buf );
```

It's up to you to make sure that `buf[]` is large enough to hold the entire string.

It's a nice *feature* of this simplicity that the 'humidity' field (or another) could be easily suppressed with an appropriate `if()`.

Comment: You shouldn’t have to cast that `char` to `int`. That happens automagically.

Comment: @Dúthomhas (Blushing at your posting's edit. Thank you.) The cast I added just to draw attention to the single byte size of `humidity`. Air temperature to 1/100th of a degree! Who does that?? `:-)`

Comment: Better (safer) to use `if (i < sizeof(buf)) i += snprintf(buf+i, sizeof(buf)-i, "`...

Comment: @ChrisDodd You're right., _Robust_ code should always be checking boundaries before splopping bytes anywhere. The above was intended only as a quick demonstration. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me like you probably want to call

`sprintf(buf, str, temp, humidity, time);`

This should result in "Temperature is 23.45, Humidity is 87, wait for 3 secs", all in one go.

However, if calling sprintf multiple times is important to you, for some reason, you can simply escape the percent signs an appropriate number of times, so that each sprintf call evaluates one more escape. By which I mean,

```
char *str = "Temperature is %f, Humidity is %%d, wait for %%%%d secs";
float temp = 23.45;
char humidity = 87;
int time = 3;
sprintf(buf, str, temp); // "Temperature is 23.45, Humidity is %d, wait for %%d secs"
sprintf(buf2, buf, humidity); // "Temperature is 23.45, Humidity is 87, wait for %d secs"
sprintf(buf3, buf2, time);  // "Temperature is 23.45, Humidity is 87, wait for 3 secs"
```

Comment: UV for ingenuity of "%%%%". `:-)`

Comment: `%f` better as `%.2f` to get "23.45".

Comment: A nightmare: OP decides humidity needs '%'... `...ity is %%d%%%%%%%%, wait...` `:-)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%n` to track output length. You also must separate the format string into its constituent parts.

```
int n1, n2;
sprintf( buf, "Temperature is %f, %n", temp, &n1 );
sprintf( buf+n1, "Humidity is %d, %n", humidity, &n2 );
sprintf( buf+n1+n2, "wait for %d secs", time );
```

You could also just use `strchr()`:

```
*buf = 0;
sprintf( strchr( buf, 0 ), "Temperature is %f, ", temp );
sprintf( strchr( buf, 0 ), "Humidity is %d, ", humidity );
sprintf( strchr( buf, 0 ), "wait for %d secs", time );
```

Honestly, though, [Fe2O3’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75380692/2706707) is simplest, heh.